# Does it matter where to put the FILTER keyword in the SPARQL code block?

Tags: filtering, sparql, ontology

I am trying to get all sub-classes (child classes) in an ontology alongside their information and then select the information related to "precentral gyrus" from the [FMA](http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/fma.owl) ontology:

```
        #selecting all sub-classes that include "precentral gyrus"
        select distinct ?parts ?name ?id ?propName ?comment
        where {

          #finding sub-classes
          ?c a ?class. 
          ?parts rdfs:subClassOf ?class.

          #getting the info
          optional {?parts rdfs:label ?name.}
          optional {?parts fma:FMAID ?id.}
          optional {?property a rdf:Property.
            optional {?property rdfs:label ?propName}}
          optional {?parts rdfs:comment ?comment.}

          #filtering related info - moved to the beginning  
          filter contains(lcase(str(?name)), "precentral gyrus").         
        }
        order by ?id
        limit 100
```

The thing is if I move the `FILTER` keyword to the beginning of the block, I still get the same results partially shown in this image:
[image]
When I put the filter at the beginning of the code, even the `?name` variable which is used in the `FILTER` command is not defined yet at the time the `FILTER`  is doing its job (filtering precentral gyrus)! Why is that?

I have an additional question too. Is the part of the code with two `OPTIONAL` block inside another one correct?

Comment: the position of a FILTER inside a basic graph pattern doesn't matter. and yes, you can put an OPTIONAL inside another OPTIONAL. What obviously is wrong is that you use `rdf:Property` in predicate position of the triple pattern. That's clearly wrong, it is a class, so you can use it like `s rdf:type rdf:Property` but not like what you did

Comment: and what is not defined when? I do not understand

Comment: @AKSW Aha! I still have not got the hang of it and sometimes have this problem of using triples in the wrong order! At first I thought you can query the triple in any order like `?object ?predicate ?subject` and the SPARQL processor will put everything in its place! So, let me see if get this correct: In a triple, always first comes a class, then a predicate and then another class, literal or variable. Am I correct?

Comment: @AKSW I also fixed the question. I meant if we put the `FILTER` command at the beginning of the code, the `?name` variable is not yet defined, but the `FILTER` is using it! However, I realized maybe the `FILTER` command creates the `?name` at that stage! In other words, there is no need to define a variable for being used in the `FILTER` command; it possibly just returns a wider set of results when the `?name` is not defined prior to use! (?)

Comment: One more time, the order doesn't matter. And the `FILTER` is executed after the triple patterns resp. the whole graph pattern has been evaluated. The `FILTER` does not "create" anything. It just filters the solution binding that come from the evaluated triple patterns.

Comment: You could also put the FILTER inside the OPTIONAL here: `optional {?parts rdfs:label ?name. filter contains(lcase(str(?name)), "precentral gyrus").   }` - the result will be the same, and a query optimizer is likely to do some FILTER push down to avoid large intermediate results which in fact are joined (or here left-outer joined) with other results.